# Allow Win 10 user to reset network adaptor via PS script without UAC

Tags: powershell, uac, windows-networking

Firstly: I have found a number of questions answered that do everything but allow me to bypass UAC.  I am IT for a small business, but it is not my primary responsibility.

I have two machines in my domain that on startup often fail to correctly connect to the domain network.  Restarting the network adapter fixes the issue until the machine restarts. Unfortunately, one of the machines is used by a non-admin, and a technically illiterate one at that.

I hoped to use a powershell script to do this. Using this website, I created script and batch files to solve the issue.  Since the computer only has one network adaptor, I went simple:
internet.ps1

```
    Get-NetAdapter | Restart-NetAdapter
```

internet.cmd

```
    @ECHO OFF
    SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
    SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%internet.ps1
    PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Unfortunately, I don't fully understand the last command in the batch file.  As such I struggle to research the command to pass some form of user credential. This environment is not very secure. But I don't want to give this user domain admin permissions generally, or provide them with some admin credentials which would end up on a sticky note. Either option is just inviting trouble from my older, technically illiterate colleagues. And going over to punch in credentials every day is time consuming.

I am looking for a script that cycles the network adaptor and provides the necessary credentials to make that change so a non-admin user can fix their domain and internet access without having admin credentials on a post-it note.

Comment: You could schedule a task with the right credentials and give the user permission to run the task

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that restarting the network adapter is only a "band-aid," and a better fix would be to address the underlying problem and configure the GPO settings that apply to those machines to wait for the network at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a task using the Task Scheduler in Windows. When scheduling a task, you can specify credentials for the task to use when it runs. You can add a trigger for this task to have it run when the computer starts, or you can simply allow the user to manually start it.

If you decide to go this route, there is a check box you can check that runs the program with the highest possible privileges. The entire point of that last line is to start a new PowerShell window that runs as administrator so it actually has permission to restart the adapter. This means that you can get rid of almost your entire script, and just keep the part that actually restarts the adapter.

For example, when you go to create a new task in Task Scheduler, under the Actions tab, you can create a new action and enter the following:


Program/script:

```
PowerShell
```

Add arguments:

```
-Command "Get-NetAdapter | Restart-NetAdapter"
```

**Note:**  I'm not sure if this is still the case, but in my past experience, sometimes it will try to run before Windows is fully loaded. If it doesn't seem to be doing anything on startup, you may need to add a delay to it. You can do this by running the `Start-Sleep` command. You can add it to the arguments field by doing the following:

```
-Command "Start-Sleep 5; Get-NetAdapter | Restart-NetAdapter"
```

Replace the number 5 with how many seconds you would like it to wait.